# Dos formularios en un mismo documentos dentro de Tabs Bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap-4, blade

Tengo unos Tabs en Bootstrap y dentro de ellos dos formularios similares, necesito que solo se envíen los datos de la pestaña actual (En las cuales se completan los campos), pero al hacerlo me muestra un error que los campos deben ser completados, y eso es porque el segundo formulario no está completado, a continuación les muestro el código:

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
     <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Clientes</a>
     <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Google Adsense</a>
    </div>
</nav>
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active py-4" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">

            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group text-left col-md-6">
                    {{ Form::text('title', NULL, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Título']) }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-left col-md-6">
                    {{ Form::text('description', NULL, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Descripción']) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-left">
                 {{ Form::submit('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-red btn-block']) }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade py-4" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">

            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group text-left col-md-6">
                    {{ Form::text('title', NULL, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Título']) }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-left col-md-6">
                {{ Form::textArea('description', NULL, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Descripción']) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-left">
                {{ Form::submit('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-red btn-block']) }}
        </div>
 </div>
```

Ambos formularios van al mismo controlador, `form-action={{ route('mi-ruta') }}`

La validación la hago en Laravel no en el form

Comment: Muy posiblemente al preparar los forms asignas el atributo required; si es así debes **togglearlo** ligando un evento a los tabs, porque Bootstrap no lo hace por tí. Sólo cambia la visibilidad de los bloques asociados. De esa forma aseguras que los validadores no **chillen** al encontrar los elementos ocultos vacíos.

Comment: Disculpa no lo especifiqué, la validación la hago en Laravel no en el form

Comment: incluye un campo oculto y toggleale el valor dependiendo del tab activo, ligando un evento click a los tabs sin anular su default, cuando recibas el post sabes que parte se valida y que parte se ignora.

Comment: Voy a leer al repecto, gracias!

Comment: Ocultando el div funciona? estoy intentando pero no logro verificar si lo oculta, me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: Se me acaba de ocurrir una idea simple: diferencia las dos acciones submit así: `Form::submit('guardar1', ... y Form::submit('guardar2'...` en el controlador sabes cual de los dos botones actuó y en consecuencia sabes que campos validas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso debe funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Acaba de tener una situación parecida, en mi aplicación tengo un pagina para la edición de usuarios, esta cuenta con un tab de 3 pestañas, Formulario, Roles y Permisos.
Cuento con 3 formularios, uno en cada pestaña . El problema radica que al enviar cualquiera de los 3 formularios, siempre se va a mostrar el tab 1 del formulario de usuarios. Esto no daría una buena experiencia para le usuario. Para tratar de solucionarlo, intente usar variables de sesión pero obtuve al 100 el resultado que esperaba, por lo tanto opté por el caché.

Aquí muestro como lo resolví

https://programaciondabs.blogspot.com/2021/06/manejo-de-formularios-en-varios-tabs-en.html

Comment: Sería mejor que publicases aquí la resolución del problema. Si pasado mañana esa página no existe, la solución se ha perdido